# drag and drop into textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying create a textbox and a draggable button.

At the moment when I click on the button a certain text is added to the begging of the textbox (JavaScript and HTML).

I want to add an option to drag the button into the textbox which will cause the same text from when I click on the button to be added into the textbox.

If it possible I also would like to choose where to add this text. I.e if I drag the button and drag in middle of a sentence in the textbox, it will add the text to the middle of the sentence where I dropped the text and not at the start of the textbox.

Thanks from advance.

**Edit:**

Here is part of the code i already did, sorry it a little messy (for what i'm doing i need all to put all in string).

```
var emoticon1 = "<input title='curious' onclick='add_tag("+'"curious"'+");' type='image' id='cur' src='/content/modules/dev/emoticons/curious.png' style='height:48px;width:48px;' />";
var emoticon2 = "<input title='confused' onclick='add_tag("+'"confused"'+");' type='image' id='con' src='/content/modules/dev/emoticons/confused.png' style='height:48px;width:48px;' />";
var emoticon3 = "<input title='helpful' onclick='add_tag("+'"helpful"'+");' type='image' id='help' src='/content/modules/dev/emoticons/helpful.png' style='height:48px;width:48px;' />";
var emoticon4 = "<input title='intersted' onclick='add_tag("+'"intersted"'+");' type='image' id='inte' src='/content/modules/dev/emoticons/interested.png' style='height:48px;width:48px;' />";
var tmp = "var txt=document.getElementById('commentTB').value;txt='#' + type + ' ' + txt ;document.getElementById('commentTB').value=txt;";

var fun = "<script> function add_tag(type) {"+tmp+"} </script>";
var emoticonsList = fun + emoticon1 + emoticon2 + emoticon3 + emoticon4;
```

The result at the moment:
[how the current code looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIauH.png)

At the moment (I work in ubuntu if it matters), if run it in chrome, it let me drag the buttons (the pictures) and put them in the text, but it put the "src" in the textbox instead of the text i want. On the other hand, in firefox the buttons can't be dragged, even if add draggable="true".

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Added what i did so far in Edit.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with Drag & Drop-API.

```js
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', event.target.innerHTML);
    });
```

```css
#buttons p {
  appearance:button;
  -moz-appearance:button; 
  -webkit-appearance:button;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <p draggable="true" id="1">This</p>
  <p draggable="true" id="2">is</p>
  <p draggable="true" id="3">a</p>
  <p draggable="true" id="4">simple</p>
  <p draggable="true" id="5">Drag'n'Drop-Test</p>
</div>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Tested in Chrome & Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've done so far so it's difficult to help but it sounds like jQuery UI could be useful here

Check out the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) functions